# Child Branch - Child Branch - Master - Git

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

Hi I have a master branch and I made a branch out of it(lets call it Branch A). I needed to implement a different feature off that branch and I created a branch out of branch A(lets say Branch B). Now Branch A is merged to master. How do I merge Branch B to master?

```
                         ------------------
                        /  BRANCH B
               ---------------------------
              /     BRANCH A
-----------------------------------------
       MASTER
```

Now it looks like this:

```
                         ------------------
                        /  BRANCH B
               ---------------------------
              /     BRANCH A
-----------------------------------------
       MASTER + BRANCH A CHANGES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to merge B like you merge A. Git will now how to handle the already merged commits from A.

```
git checkout master
git merge B
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can do it the same way as any other merge.

I think people get a little too hung up on branch identity - or, more to the point, people conflate a "branch" (a movable ref; i.e. a name that points to some commit) with a set of commits.  Taking your example

```
x --- O --- x --- x <--(master)
       \
        A1 --- A2 --- A3 <--(branchA)
                 \
                  B1 --- B2 <--(branchB)
```

Now `branchA` is a pointer that happens to currently point to `A3`.  Many people think that `branchA` *is* the set of commits (`A1`, `A2`, `A3`) and so they reason incorrectly about what it means to delete the branch, or merge it, or rebase it, or operate on it in any way.

When you merged `branchA` to `master`, git didn't care about anything like that.  It just saw that `O` was the closest commit reachable from both `branchA` and `master`; that `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` were reachable from `branchA` but not from `O`; and maybe that various `x` commits were reachable from `master` but not from `O`.  It used that information to calculate the merge (and asked you for help if it got into any difficulty doing so), then left you with

```
x --- O --- x --- x ----- M <--(master)
       \                 /
        A1 --- A2 --- A3 <--(branchA)
                 \
                  B1 --- B2 <--(branchB)
```

So now if you merge `branchB` git will probably identify `A2` as the most recent commit reachable from both `branchB` and `master`; `B1` and `B2` as commits reachable from `branchB` but not from `A2`; and maybe `M`, `A3`, and various `x` commits as reachable from `master` but not from `A2`.  And it's likely to calculate the resulting merge just fine.

*That said*, if it doesn't go smoothly, you could simplify things for git by checking out `branchA` (or `A3`, which is maybe tricky but still doable if you've deleted `branchA`), merging `branchB`, then checking out `master` and again merging `branchA`.  This breaks the merge calculation into two smaller/simpler parts, and results in a merge topology which (depending on your preferences) is either more symmetric and therefore neater, or more cluttered with merges and therefore uglier.

Comment: Note I had a flurry of edits for typos, at least one of which corrected a very nonsensical statement I originally made.  So you may want to read over it again.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can merge `B` into `master` (assume `A` is merged into `master` at commit `K`):

```
A---B---C---D--------K  master
     \              /
       E---F---G---H    Branch A
            \
             I---G      Branch B
```

**Option 1: rebase B onto A, and then merge B into master**

`git rebase --onto A A B`, then the branch structure will look like:

```
A---B---C---D--------K        master
     \              /
       E---F---G---H          Branch A
                    \
                     I'---G'  Branch B
```

Then merge B into master (`git merge B`):

```
A---B---C---D-------K---------L  master
     \             /         /
      E---F---G---H         /    Branch A
                   \       /
                    I'---G'      Branch B
```

**Option 2: merge B into master directly** (this is will cause more conflicts)

`git merge  B`

```
A---B---C---D--------K---L   master
     \              /   /
      E---F---G---H    /     Branch A
           \          /
            I--------G       Branch B
```

Comment: Those are two of the many ways; not the only (or necessarily best) two ways.  Also note that `rebase --onto A A B` is long-hand for `rebase A B`, as the listed upstream is the default target onto which the rebase will be done.